# E-mail only working sometimes in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, email, active-directory

Whenever I create or start a simple workflow with an email action I receive this message:

```
11/19/2013 9:41 AM  Error   
No presence informationadministrator
**Coercion warning: user or group does not have a valid e-mail address.**

11/19/2013 9:41 AM  Error   
No presence information System Account
**The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.**  

11/19/2013 9:41 AM  Error   
No presence informationSystem Account
The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.

11/19/2013 9:41 AM  Workflow Initiated  
No presence informationadministrator
Collect Feedback was started. Participants: TestUser
    11/19/2013 9:41 AM  Task Created    
No presence informationadministrator
Task created for TestUser. Due by: 1/3/2014 9:41:47 AM
```

The e-mail in Active Directory is correct and the weird thing is that I am able to send mails when I click on "Share" to the same user:

[image: "Share" does work and sends a mail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I finally found the solution for my case. I don't know why it works but I deleted all the users in my Active Directory and created new ones (with the same emails).

It all works now.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! If possible, you can mark your own post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Delete affected users in site collection resolve the problemm. The main reason is changing email address in Active Directory.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than deleting the user from AD which is a bit drastic. I think the problem is the copy of the user properties in the SP user list gets out of sync and doesn't reflect the later changes in AD. This is one way of fixing it.